# php page gives 500 error but executed via ssh works

Tags: php, linux, ssh, composer-php

I'm missing something easy I think:

Testing a mailgun install on an EC2 Linux instance.

The following code works when I use a putty session:

```
php /var/www/html/[thefilebelow.php]
```

But fails when I go to a browser and use

```
http://myexample.com/[thefilebelow.php]
```

That gives a 500 error

[thefilebelow.php]:

```
 # Include the Autoloader (see "Libraries" for install instructions)
require '/home/ec2-user/vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

# Instantiate the client. 
$mgClient = new Mailgun('kxxxxxxxxxx');
$domain = "mg.myexample.com";

# Make the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'bob <info@lxxxxx.com>',
    'to'      => 'Steve <xxxxx@gmail.com>',
    'subject' => 'Hello',
    'text'    => 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
));
```

ERROR LOG:

> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed op ning required '/home/ec2-user/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear7:/usr/share/php7') in /var/www/html/myfilebelow.php on line 3

Just to be clear - the location of the require file is correct.

Permissions for /var/www/htmlmyfilebelow.php ec2-user:www

Permissions for /home/ec2-user/vendor/ ec2-user:www

(permissions are the same for include file and script)

Comment: Why would the web server be able to read a file in a user's home directory?

Comment: `ec2-user:www` shows that owner is ec2-user and group is www but what about the mode (644, 755, etc). Ingnacio's comment is also pertinent.

Comment: Honestly, not 100% sure. So probably messed up the composer installation?  Any idea on how to back that out?  It's a test server, I can always grab a new image.

Comment: yea, ignacio's comment make total sense. Not sure why I thought that would work.  So when I installed composer, somehow I messed up the directory. time to google - "move composer installation"

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is that when installing composer on an ec2 instance (and generally on other servers), be sure to navigate out of the landing directory when opening a an ec2-user session in putty, if the landing directory is your user directory.

Move up to /var/www/ or some other directory owned by the www group.